# Estimation of the absulute value of a complex double sum

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ let $a_i, b_{i, j} \in \mathbb{C}$ be complex numbers such that $| a_i | = | b_{i, j} | = 1$.
I am interested in possible estimations of
$$
\left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right|.
$$

Note that for the application that I have in mind the estimation via the triangular inequality
$$\left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right| \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left| a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right|$$
is too coarse.

In particular I would like to know whether the inequality

$$\left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right| \leq \left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left| \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right|^2 \right|$$

is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality
$$\left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right| \leq \left| \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left| \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} \right|^2 \right|$$
cannont hold ; here is a counter-example. Let $x>0$, $n=2$, $a_1=a_2=1$, $b_{1,1}=b_{2,1}=e^{ix}$ and $b_{1,2}=b_{2,2}=-1$

Then
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j} =  (e^{ix}-1)+(e^{ix}-1)= 2(e^{ix}-1)$$
and
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left|\sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right|^2 =  |e^{ix}-1|^2+|e^{ix}-1|^2= 2|e^{ix}-1|^2$$

As $x \to 0^+$, we have $e^{ix}=1+ix + o_{x \to 0^+}(x)$ and we get :
$$\left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right| \underset{x \to 0^+}{\sim} 2|ix| \underset{x \to 0^+}{\sim} 2x$$
and
$$\left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left|\sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right|^2\right| \underset{x \to 0^+}{\sim} 2|i x|^2 \underset{x \to 0^+}{\sim} 2x^2$$
Thus, for $x$ small enough, $\left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left|\sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right|^2\right|< \left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right| $. Moreover, this shows that there is no constant $C$ such that
$$\left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right| \leqslant C \left|\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i \cdot \left|\sum_{j = 1}^{n} b_{i, j}\right|^2\right|.$$